# Making async calls for each record in php

Tags: php, asynchronous, slim, guzzle

I have a file with 100 records. I want to read each record and pass it to another function.
However, since there are 100 records, I wish to trigger in async manner.

Current code :

```
foreach ($records as $record) {
   $this->myFunction($record);  //how to make this trigger all the function calls in one go ?
}

public function myFunction($record) {
   //api call1;
   //api call2;
   //....
}
```

Comment: Are you using `curl` to perform the API calls? You could use `curl_multi`

Comment: Other than that, PHP doesn't have native async threads.

Comment: You may not want to do this in another thread. Apache (one of the most common servers for PHP), uses a single thread per request. There are a limit to the number of threads. If you increase the threads per request, you decrease the amount of requests that can happen at the same time

Comment: @Barmar those API calls are supposed to be run in sequence for each of the records

Comment: Can you elaborate on the async nature? Do you want to perform other PHP work, or are you planning on showing a progress bar? Is this GUI or CLI? I would recommend looking into queues and task runners.

Comment: this is from CLI. I want to keep processing with other php work, but for each record in one go.

Comment: You may consider pushing these calls as "messages" into a RabbitMQ queue and process it from the consumers.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO ... "no, you really don't."

You do **not** want to "light yet-another flaming arrow and fire it into the air," such that you now have 100 flaming arrows crashing down on the target and tomorrow there might be 400."  You need to exercise *control* over the process.  No matter how many "units of work" may need to be processed, you need to control how many can be worked-on at the same time.  What you need is a so-called ***"workflow*** **engine."**  Google it ...